# Copy data from source and return to main wb

Tags: excel, vba

```
SUB Copy_paste_ data()

 Dim source as string

 Dim template as Thisworkbook 

 Msgbox "Open the BLI RAW DATA WORKBOOK",,"BLI"

Source = Application.GetopenFilename()

Workbooks.open (source)

Range("A1"). select

Rows("3:4").Select

Selection.Delete shift:xlup

Range("A1"). select

Range("A4:F4"). select

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)). select

Selection.copy

Thisworkbook.activate

Sheets("Sheet1").select

Range("A1").Select

Selection.paste, paste:=xlpastevalues

End sub
```

I couldn't activate previous workbook run time error 9 subscript out of range is occuring kindly give me a solution

Comment: I couldn't activate previous workbook run time error 9 subscript out of range is occuring kindly give me a solution

Comment: `Dim template as Thisworkbook ` is this right? Shouldn't this be `Dim template as Workbook `? Also, which line does arise the error?

Comment: If there is more than one sheet in the source workbook, what is the worksheet's name that you want to copy the data from? After the operations, do you want to save the source workbook (you have just deleted two rows)?

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Values of a Range to Another Workbook

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Copy_paste_data()

    MsgBox "Open the BLI RAW DATA WORKBOOK", , "BLI"
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim swbPath As String: swbPath = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    If swbPath = "False" Then
        MsgBox "You canceled.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(swbPath)
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' adjust!
    
    sws.Rows("3:4").Delete xlShiftUp
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(sws.Range("A4:F4").Cells, _
        sws.Range("A4:F4").End(xlDown))
    
    ' Destination
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim drg As Range
    Set drg = dws.Range("A1").Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count)
    
    ' Copy by assignment (most efficient).
    
    drg.Value = srg.Value
        
    ' Save and Close
    
    swb.Close SaveChanges:=False ' set to 'True' if you want to save
    'dwb.Save
    
    ' Inform.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Data copied.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```